# TextBox with background image and color

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a TextBox control and I would like to be able to set a background image and a background color.

Currently I can set one, or the other but not both. When I try to set both simultaneously I receive a "The property 'Background' is set more than once" error.

Here is the code I used:

```
<TextBox Name="tbImageTextBox">
      <TextBox.Background>
           <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/Images/image.png" 
                  AlignmentX="Right" Stretch="None"/>
           <SolidColorBrush>#FF8D8A8A</SolidColorBrush>
      </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

I have also attempted to set the background color in the style for the TextBox and the image in the `<TextBox.Background>`, but the color is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up putting the TextBox into a grid with the Background color set and applying the background image to the TextBox itself as using VisualBrush and DrawingBrush stretched my image or only applied the background color to the image - not the rest of the TextBox.

Comment: This is the solution I used, much more straightforward than using the Visual or Drawing brushes.

Comment: I am trying to create a custom style for my textbox to make it look flatter and have a bound background colour AND add an image based on some data trigger. When using a standard textbox I can do exactly as you have said here and it works well but the border looks rubbish (I am making a grid from the textboxes). So I need to understand how to have my custom style pick up the containers background colour, any ideas?

Comment: @Akuma have you set the border to be transparent?

Answer (score 7):

Use the grid resource for background as needed. Same resource can be used for multiple textboxes.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="img" ImageSource="Blue hills.jpg"></ImageBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brownBrush" Color="Brown"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBox x:Name="test" Background="{StaticResource img}" Width="100" Height="40" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to combine the colour and the image in a single `Brush` instance, you could use a [`DrawingBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx) or a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) containing an `Image` control with your image and the `Background` set to the colour for example.

Comment: I am having trouble with this approach with the stretching of my image. If I set Stretch=None, only the image has the background color applied, not the rest of the TextBox. If I don't set Stretch="None" then the image is stretched across the whole TextBox.

Is there a way around this?

<VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Grid Background="DarkGray">
                                <Image Source="image.jpg"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>

Comment: @binncheol: Well, i would recommend looking into the drawing brush, the visual brush is a bit hacky anyway. Maybe this article can help you get started: [Drawing with Images, Drawings and Visuals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749021.aspx) | If you must use the visual brush: You can try to bind the Grid size to the (actual) TextBlock size.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want either a `VisualBrush` or a `DrawingBrush`.  More information on those can be found at MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx).  Something like this might get you started:

```
<Rectangle Width="75" Height="75">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile">
      <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Grid>
          <Image BaseUri="somepic.png" />
          <Rectangle Brush="FF8D8A8A" />  
        </Grid>
      </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```